# How can I repeatedly update the plotly xaxis range in R

Tags: r, plotly

I want to use plotly to display consecutive (x) subsets of a larger data.frame of x and y. I can change the xaxis range initially, but cannot update it. Eventually I would like this to be driven by a button press, but first just trying to update the plot.

```
library(plotly)
t <- 1:1000
y <- runif(1000)
dat <- data.frame(t,y)
fig <- plot_ly(dat, x=~t, y=~y, type='scatter', mode='lines')
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis=list(range=list(1,100)))
print(fig)         # correctly plots only 1-100
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis=list(range=list(101,200)))
print(fig)         # doesn't update, still plots only 1-100
fig <- fig %>% style(layout=list(xaxis=list(range=list101,200)))
print(fig)         # this also doesn't update, still plots only 1-100
```

Comment: If you don't re-assign to `fig`, you will see that  your call `layout(xaxis=list(range(list(1,100)))` works without a problem; by reassigning, you are adding additional layouts, and only the first xaxis range layout is rendered.

Comment: Can't get this to work: "layout(xaxis=list(range(list(1,100)))" does not modify fig: subsequent print (fig) has default xaxis range

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. As long as I reference the fig, Langtang's solution works:
layout(fig, xaxis=list(range(list(1,100))))